# Is there a way to open everything in my park at once?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I'm building a park in sandbox mode and it's so boring and takes forever to go around clicking each vendor and setting it to 'open'. Is there a shortcut for opening everything simultaneously?

Comment: I remember there because a kind of info screen with all of your rides and other attractions. I would assume there's a button to open or close all from there. Also if you click on the park entrance there's an open / close but I'm not sure if it affects everything inside or just whether or not people can enter the park.

Comment: You should post this as an answer. I did indeed find "open/close all attractions" under the info screen that lists your attractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version of my comment:

I remember there being an info screen listing all of your rides and other attractions. There's a button to open or close all from there.